# Can I indicate deprecated in sphinx search?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, deprecated

Is it possible for sphinx to add a deprecated label in the search results so that users know to avoid this function before opening the link? I need the deprecated functions to be available but to steer users away from them.

I have added the `..deprecated::` field in my docs but it does not show up in the search.